# How to recreate 3-position switch using two momentary buttons?

Tags: diagram

I have a 3-position switch (look at diagram below). Normally it is in neutral position, it can be switched either UP or DOWN (momentary action, goes back to neutral when I stop pushing). This is done by 3 wires.

I want to start using **two** momentary ON-OFF buttons instead of this one switch. Functionality should remain the same (same table).

Do you have any idea how a diagram should look like for such buttons? How they should be connected using those 3 wires? One button should be for UP action, second for DOWN action.

[image]